# OpenFileDialog open folder with exe

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

How can I promptly open application's folder  using OpenFileDialog ?

```
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
           ...........

        }
```

Comment: What does "open folder" mean? And "promptly"?

Comment: i call OpenFileDialog and it shows me a folder with my exe, not c:\\

Comment: Your question is still not clear. Do you mean "OpenFileDialog starts in my application's folder"? Please edit your question and add the information there, instead of adding it in the comments, so that people can see it.

Comment: Yep man application's folder

Comment: How are you setting the path, show us your code please

Answer (score 6):

Guessing that you mean "Show the OpenFileDialog starting in my application's folder", just set the `OpenFileDialog.InitialDir` to your application's folder before showing the `OpenFileDialog`.

```
string AppPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);;
openFileDialog1.InitialDir = AppPath;
```

If you need help finding your application's directory, see [Getting root folder of application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5908343/62576)

Answer (score 2):

Use the [FileDialog.InitialDirectory Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.initialdirectory.aspx) if you wish to override one of the default ways for its value getting set (described on MSDN).

```
openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";  // based on comment of question
```