# Directory structure - what path should I use?

Tags: c#

I have created a WindowsApp.exe under Application\Setup folder. Now I want to create a Database under Application\Database folder from WindowsApp.exe

What should be the path given to the filename here?

Comment: you mean in a folder named database where application is installed?

Comment: Application\Setup\WindowsApp.exe is the exe location. Application\Database\db1.mdb is database location. Now I am running WindowsApp.exe and want to create db1.mdb as mentioned

Comment: try the relative path "Database\db1.mdb"

Comment: Thanks for the immediate replies. But WindowsApp.exe is running under Setup folder. We need to go back one step and then access Database folder

Comment: in that case simply use "..\Database\db1.mdb"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908343/getting-root-folder-of-application

Comment: Thanks a lot. But point here. If WindowsApp.exe is under Application\Main\Setup\WindowsApp.exe and Database is just under Application\Database. Now I want to come back 2 steps back and use Database\db1.mdb. So if I put one more dot "." like this to "...\Database\db1.mdb", Will this work?

Comment: if you want it under application then simply reach that folder by getting the current folder which is a child and cut the rest of the path

Comment: look at the updated answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
    Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Database\\db1.mdb")
```

**Edit**

since you want the parent folder you can go up one folder by doing

```
    Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory.Substring(Environment.CurrentDirectory.LastIndexOf("\\")), "Database\\db1.mdb")
```

**Edit 2**

if you want  the Application folder even if its N times above the current folder then you can reach it by doing this

```
    var index = Environment.CurrentDirectory.IndexOf(Environment.CurrentDirectory.IndexOf("ApplicationRootFolderName"),"\\")
    var AppRootPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory.Substring(0,index);
```

**Edit 3**

As mentioned by [Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/279906/michael) its better to get the parent folder using this way

```
    Directory.GetParent(Environment.CurrentDirectory).FullName
```

Comment: For getting the parent folder I'd use `Directory.GetParent(Environment.CurrentDirectory).FullName`. May as well use the built-in framework.

Comment: you are absolutely right, thanks for the reminder :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael and MEYWD