# Get File Path of A File In Your Current Project

Tags: c#

How do I programmically get the File Path of a File In my project?

```
 string fileContent = File.ReadAllText(LocalConstants.EMAIL_PATH);
```

The EMAIL_PATH I added to my project as a text file. This line of code throws an exception because by default it is looking in the system32 folder for some reason. I need to set it to the projects directory.

Comment: Do you need the application directory?

Comment: I add a text file to my project. I need that directory

Comment: The projects root directory is what I need

Comment: Are you trying to embed a txt file into your executable?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You could use [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx) and [`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.basedirectory.aspx):

```
string fileName = "SampleFile.txt";
string path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, LocalConstants.EMAIL_PATH, fileName);
```

Returns in a test project in debug mode this path(when `LocalConstants.EMAIL_PATH="Emails"`):

```
C:\****\****\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WindowsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\bin\Debug\Emails\SampleFile.txt
```

Comment: This code points to the bin/Debug folder. EMAIL_PATH is in the root folder of the project

Comment: Maybe my problem is I have to set the text files to copy to output. Is that the standard thing to do?

Comment: @NickLaMarca: You're refering to http://stackoverflow.com/a/857473/284240 ? Maybe, depends on your exact requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Environment.CurrentDirectory`

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.currentdirectory.aspx

For further reading.

edit*

`string temp = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);`

Will do the same and is perhaps a little safer.

Comment: It will point to where ever your working directory is. I just ran a demo on a test console app and the output was: "c:\users\duane\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\EnvironmentDemo\EnvironmentDemo\bin\Debug", could you post the string you get from this property?

Comment: The current directory isn't always the directory of your application. If it's a support file then it's not safe to assume this.

Comment: Incorrect! This is the current working directory, not the directory your project is being served from.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString()