# How to get Current Project path of the file having 5 project solution

Tags: c#

I have 5 Project in One solution In that Email service is one of the Class library i have when i try to get the Directory path its return main project path only here my code.

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()+ ".EmailService")
                .AddJsonFile("appsetting.json");
            IConfigurationRoot configuration = builder.Build();
```

extra i have added a ".EmailService". there is any solution to get path?

Comment: here some ways to get the path: https://yetanotherchris.dev/csharp/6-ways-to-get-the-current-directory-in-csharp/

Comment: why did you add `".EmialService"`??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get File Path of A File In Your Current Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10704444/get-file-path-of-a-file-in-your-current-project)

Comment: John b actually what the builder return main project(web) path i have the appseting.json in Email service project so that i statically added ".EmailService"

Answer (score 0):

For .Net Core

Inject `IHostingEnvironment env`

`string path =env.ContentRootPath;`

For .Net framework

```
string _systemPath=System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath;
```